# Is it possible to create subdomains for localhost based on different ports?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I've got a situation when I need to share a cookie from one local app to another. I wonder whether it is possible to implement it by making one of app's addresses localhost:number a subdomain of another one localhost ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Define different domains and subdomains in `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts` file.

Comment: If you're hosting the apps in IIS, you can do URL rewrite: https://weblogs.asp.net/owscott/creating-a-reverse-proxy-with-url-rewrite-for-iis

Comment: you can also specify in hosts using a wildcard `127.0.0.1 *.localhost.com`

Answer (score 0):

If you use a port it's not a subdomain but a different domain.

If you really need a subdomain set it in the hosts file

In Windows `c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts`

In Linux `/etc/hosts`

```
127.0.0.1    domain.test
127.0.0.1    subdomain.domain.test
```

Comment: Not sure I understand how this will help

Comment: If you just want to test cookie sharing between different apps use a different ports. For cookie's localhost:3000 and localhost:4000 - it's a different domain. But if you have only one instance of the app that should have different logic depends on a subdomain - use hosts file.